# How do you say "Availability to travel to workplace" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

I am creating a resume for working remotely and I want to mention that I am available to travel to the workplace, but we need to talk about this availability before signing the contract.

I am thinking of calling it as such:

> Monatliche Reiseverfügbarkeit zum Arbeitsplatz nach Gespräch

... but I don't know if it makes sense, as Reise might be more tourism related, and the whole construct sounds wrong.
What would be a good way to say it? Thank you.

Comment: The answer depends, I think. Do you mean that you work remotely and can occasionally come in? Does it refer to business trips to external locations, like clients, construction or drilling sites? How is your usual work location (home?) related to the work place you talk about? What do you mean with "monthly"? How often, how long typically?
The sentence could be ok, but it should end with "... nach Absprache"

Comment: Thank you, thats what I meant, "nach Absprache" but forgot the correct expression. I meant that I work from home but can occasionally come in, for a week per month.

Comment: @luator Ops, sorry :-) I really misread something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's actually long distance (e.g. you live in London but could come to Germany for a couple days) *Reise* is a fitting word. But you wouldn't *reisen* to your place of work. However, despite German offering virtually endless combinations for compound words, I'd phrase this differently

> Bereitschaft, den Arbeitsort monatlich persönlich aufzusuchen

or

> Ich bin bereit, für einige Tage im Monat persönlich am Arbeitsort zu sein

No need to specify *nach Absprache* in your resume. That's a discussion saved for an interview.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the ability (and willingness) to travel is called *Reisebereitschaft* in job adverts and resumes. When you want to express this should be agreed on a case-by-case basis, attribute it with "nach Absprache". So,

> Reisebereitschaft nach Absprache vorhanden.

Comment: Typically *Reisebereitschaft* describes eagerness for travels from working place to customers, however.

Comment: @guidot Nope. It means "willingness and ability to travel" - No implication of from where to where. My personal contract says exactly so, and the situation is similar to that of the OP (Working from home with frequent visits to the employment site)

Comment: Agree with @guidot. While the literal meaning is broader, in this context the destination "customer" is implied.

Comment: @tofro: "No implication of from where to where." - I disagree with this as a general statement. You can have "keine Reisebereitschaft" and still be expected to show up at your desk in the company building. It may depend on the job and context, but I, too, know the typical usage of "Reisebereitschaft" to refer to travelling *elsewhere* than your own company's building (actually, no matter whether you "normally" work there or from home). The point is that "Reise" in "Reisebereitschaft" is usually understood as referring to "Dienstreise", which the regular commute doesn't count as.